# Get before last position of string in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, string, split

I have a question about SQL Server.

I want get data before last IN character position.

Table `Stringposition`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Stringposition]
(
    [Name] [varchar](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Stringposition] ([Name]) 
VALUES (N'PN MAIN DOOR IN'), (N'PN PASSAGE IN'),
       (N'INTestingIN'), (N'YENINFgh'), (N'inGENTRINin')
GO
```

Expecting output data like below:

```
Name
--------------
PN MAIN DOOR
PN PASSAGE 
INTesting
YEN
inGENTRIN
```

I tried this query:

```
select 
    substring(name, 0, charindex('in', name, charindex('in', name) + 1)),
    name 
from 
    [dbo].[Stringposition]
```

but this query not returning the expected result.

Please tell me how to write a query to achieve this task in SQL Server.

Comment: Side note: since your columns is defined a `VARCHAR(100)`, it is a **non**-Unicode column. When you insert, you **must NOT** use the `N'....'` notation - that causes the string literals to be considered as **Unicode** - and then they have to be converted back to **non-Unicode** to match the datatype. If you use `VARCHAR`, you should use `INSERT INTO .. VALUES('abc');` (**without** the `N` prefix!)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(name, 1, LEN(name) - CHARINDEX('ni', REVERSE(name)) - 1)  
FROM stringposition
```

OUTPUT

```
NAME
-----------------
PN MAIN DOOR   
PN PASSAGE  
INTesting  
YEN  
inGENTRIN
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT('your string', LEN('your string') - CHARINDEX(REVERSE('your special string'), REVERSE('your string')) - 1)))
FROM stringposition
```